# How to show that throttling has occurred in camel

Tags: java, apache-camel, throttling

I wanted to know if there was a way to do something like `System.out.println();` or log that throttling has occurred. The only way I can see at the moment if throttling has occurred is by setting rejectExecution to True. The problem with that is that if it set to true then the request isn't is processed when throttling occurs. Is there a way to notify that throttling has occurred using camel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Throttler EIP in Camel is implemented using class [`Throttler`](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/camel-core/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/processor/Throttler.java) which extends from [`DelayProcessorSupport`](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/camel-core/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/processor/DelayProcessorSupport.java) which logs messages at trace level regarding it's processing so you can configure its logging to trace level.
For e.g., if you are using log4j then you can use,

```
log4j.logger.org.apache.camel.processor.DelayProcessorSupport=TRACE ,file

log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=D:/output.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=5MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```